# How to work with ids and strings in pagerTabStrip

Tags: string, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Super newbie question about accessing information in strings. I have chunked together an app that uses a fragmentpager and the PagerTabStrip.

It is supposed to display titles on the tab, but mine displays nothing...because I am a total newbie hacking his way through. I am so grateful for this community.

From my layout file that calls the content (and once I fix it the title--id@pager_header right?):

```
<android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
    android:id="@+id/pager_header"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
```

My code that gets me the swipeable pages of content:

public class Poems extends FragmentActivity {

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.contentpage);

    /** Getting a reference to the ViewPager defined the layout file */        
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    /** Getting fragment manager */
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

    /** Instantiating FragmentPagerAdapter */
    MyFragmentPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(fm);

    /** Setting the pagerAdapter to the pager object */
    pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);


}
```

}

My code that should get me the titles from the string reference file.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment{

int mCurrentPage;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    /** Getting the arguments to the Bundle object */
    Bundle data = getArguments();

    /** Getting integer data of the key current_page from the bundle */
    mCurrentPage = data.getInt("current_page", 0);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {     
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myfragment_layout, container,false);
    TextView tv = (TextView ) v.findViewById(R.id.tv);
    tv.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
    switch(mCurrentPage){
    case 0:
       tv.setText("  ");
    break;
    case 1:
        tv.setText(R.string.content_1);
    break;
    case 2:
        tv.setText(R.string.content_2);
        break;
    case 3:
        tv.setText(R.string.content_3);
        break;
                    }
        return tv;

}
```

}

How do I get pager_header from this?

A sample relevant string is:

```
<string name="content_1">Welcome to this app!</string>
```

I am thinking that I need to better understand strings since I'm coming from more of a text content background.

How do I include in the stings.xml file the indicators that allow the app to reference the content associated with pageview so that I can have that show up in the tab? How I do make it so that the content shows "Welcome to this app" but the title in the tab shows "Home"?

I think as if each entry (page) is like a line in a database with one point of reference being the title, one being the content, one being a link or some other content. Each has its own id, right?

Thank you in advance for explaining this to a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement `getPageTitle(int position)` in `MyFragmentPagerAdapter`. The `String` that is returned from this method is used to set the title of the `PagerTabStrip`.

```
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    Log.v(TAG, "getPageTitle");

    String tabTitle;
    switch(position) {
        case 0:
            tabTitle = "Tab #0";
            break;
        case 1:
            tabTitle = "Home";
            break;
        case 2:
            tabTitle = "Tab #2";
            break;
        case 3:
            tabTitle = "Tab #3";
            break;
        default:
            tabTitle = "Default Tab Title";
            break;
    }
    return tabTitle;
}
```

You can make this more dynamic by making the title and content arguments that you pass in using a `Bundle` by calling `setArguments(Bundle args)` on your `MyFragments` that you add to your `ViewPager`. In `MyFragment` in `onCreateView()` you can then set your content based on the passed in content `String` argument. Then in `MyFragmentPagerAdapter` you can get a reference to the `Fragment` at the `position` and pull get the title directly from `MyFragment`.

Comment: Okay, I got the first suggestion working! Thank you so much! 

I like the proposition to make it more dynamic, but I have to figure that out. I will try that later tonight.